# AlamofireImage Code=-1016 "Failed to validate response due to unacceptable content type"

Tags: node.js, swift2, ios9, alamofire, alamofireimage

I have gotten the URL of an image using Alamofire and SwityJSON to parse the response obtained from an API. Later, on my code, I am trying to use AlamofireImage to set that image to an ImageView... I am trying to do the following:

```
let headers = ["Authorization": requestToken, "Content-Type": "image/jpg"]

        print(foods[indexPath.row].image)

        Alamofire.request(.GET, imageEndPoint, headers: headers)
            .responseImage { response in
                debugPrint(response)
                print(response.request)
                print(response.response)

                if let image = response.result.value {
                    print("image downloaded: \(image)")
                }
        }
```

However, when debugging, I am getting the following errors

```
 Request]: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fa93e052e60> { URL: http://159.203.92.55:9000/api/media/image?path=./server/uploads/images/products/jOqmy768a5wN2tcPd07cPhVH.jpg }
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fa93e05a0a0> { URL: http://159.203.92.55:9000/api/media/image?path=./server/uploads/images/products/jOqmy768a5wN2tcPd07cPhVH.jpg } { status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "image/jpg";
Date = "Sun, 17 Jan 2016 16:28:38 GMT";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Powered-By" = Express;
} }

[Data]: 26224 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-1016 "Failed to validate response due to unacceptable content type" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to validate response due to unacceptable content type}
Optional(<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fa93e052e60> { URL: http://159.203.92.55:9000/api/media/image?path=./server/uploads/images/products/jOqmy768a5wN2tcPd07cPhVH.jpg })
```

Obviously there is an error due to the content type but I am not sure how to solve it:

```
[Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-1016   "Failed to validate response due to unacceptable content type"  UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to validate response due to unacceptable content type}
```

Because of this error, I can't go ahead and just set the image to the imageView

```
   cell.thumbnailImageView.image = myImage
```

**When I try to do the same requests using Chrome's Postman, I get the image without any issues.**

Suggestions anyone? thanks

UPDATE: I found a way that is far from what I wanted but works

```
  Alamofire.request(.GET, foods[indexPath.row].image, headers: headers)
                .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!, scale: 1) 
           }
```

this is vanilla Alamofire, so I still haven't been able to use AlamofireImage which provides better support for images. I got this method from the following post: [How to load image in swift using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636622/how-to-load-image-in-swift-using-alamofire)   (skywinder's answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I noticed the answer from the server was **"Content-Type" = "image/jpg";** but as the user @Gomines pointed out, the correct content type for alamofireImage is actually **"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"**

Then I went back to AlamofireImages docs and read this

> If the image you are attempting to download is an invalid MIME type not in the list, you can add custom acceptable content types using the addAcceptableImageContentTypes extension on the Request type.

So I just had to add this line of code before the AlamofireImage request:

```
Request.addAcceptableImageContentTypes(["image/jpg"])
```

The problem was that I was not matching the same content type that the server was responding with. However, that line solves the issue because now AlamofireImage will also accept the same type that the server is sending.

Comment: Is this still working for you? It used to work for me. Now I'm using XCode 8 and Swift 2.3 and this hack doesn't work anymore on my code.

Comment: Yes it is working, it is not a hack just an Alamofire method

Comment: Hi @JesusAdolfoRodriguez Can you please tell exactly where to add this line. I have the same issue, but I am not getting where to use it. I have done `Alamofire.request(...).responseImage(completionHandler: )` Please help

Comment: @Bella I think this will help you https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/issues/190

Comment: @JesusAdolfoRodriguez Hey thanks. But I don't have image url. I have an api call "https://....../api/download" along with request parameters. I get image in response. I have tried the above link, but failed. :(

Comment: you don't need the image url but only to add whatever contentType te server is sending with `DataRequest.addAcceptableImageContentTypes(["image/jpg"])` replace `image/jpg` with the server's content type

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake on the content type. It should be `image/jpeg` (http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/).

```
let headers = ["Authorization": requestToken, "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"]
```

I hope this resolves the problem.

Comment: I did make that mistake and thanks for pointing it out but that doesn't change anything, I was still getting the same response but you made me realize what could be going on. Check my answer.