# Load UITableView images on background thread

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have an app that present images that sent from the server (similar to Instagram) using a tableView.

from the server I got:

- Full size image URL
- Description (String)
- Image width
- Image height

and I have a custom cell that present that as I want.

Like Instagram, the height of the image isn't fixed, so the cell's height changes dynamically to the image's height.

The image that I get from the server is really big, so I crop every image to be `Width - Screen's width, Height - Based of the width (keeps the ratio)`, like that:

```
func imageWithImage (sourceImage:UIImage, scaledToWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let oldWidth = sourceImage.size.width
    let scaleFactor = scaledToWidth / oldWidth

    let newHeight = sourceImage.size.height * scaleFactor
    let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width:newWidth, height:newHeight))
    sourceImage.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:newWidth, height:newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

my problem is that the tableView is VERY slow. So I thought of loading and cropping the images in a background thread and while its loading to present a default image.

I've tried that (using SDKs like `Alamofire`, `Kingfisher` etc...) but then the size of the cells (`UITableViewAutomaticDimension`) were a mess (because of the dynamic height), the images changed to wrong images while scrolling and sometimes even crashed while scrolling.

So that's why I'm asking here, how can I load the cells in a background thread and to keep its dynamic size, its correct photos and to avoid crashing?

Thank you very much in advanced for you answers!

Note: I know both Swift and Objective-C, select your favorite :)

Comment: have you tried `SDWebImage` library its really good option for you to achieve above requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for this. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30591816/2324548), providing both a solution using Alamofire and a custom one.

**Edited post-comments:**

For calculating the cell height based on the image, you will need to download and cache those images prior to reloading your tableView, as heightForRowAtIndexPath will be called before cellForRowAtIndexPath, so you need to know the image height before actually setting it as that cell's property. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13105218/2324548) is what you need for that.

Comment: I am using Alamofire, please pay attention to what I wrote, thanks!
`I've tried that (using Alamofire) but then the size of the cells (UITableViewAutomaticDimension) were a mess (because of the dynamic height), the images changed to wrong images while scrolling and sometimes even crashed while scrolling.`

Comment: Sorry  but there's no mention in your question of Alamofire.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think you should edit the subject of your question too, as its focused more on calculating the image height than on loading images on a back thread. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: OK, now everything is fine (`cell.imageView.setImageWith(myUrl)`), but sometimes the wrong images while scrolling

Comment: This shouldn't happen, there might be some other conflict there, try printing out the indexes of your cells at they show on screen and match them with the links and images you have in your array, see where the error might be. Also, please accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks